# Упорядочить даты по порядку

Tags: php

Есть список дат, записанных вразброс:

```
$date = '2013-12-25,2013-12-26,2013-12-27,2013-12-28,2013-12-29,2013-12-30,2013-12-31,2014-01-01,2014-01-02,2014-01-03,2014-01-04,2014-01-05,2014-01-11,2014-01-10,2014-01-09,2014-01-08,2014-01-07,2014-01-06';
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, упорядочить их по порядку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = '2013-05-20,2014-01-11,2013-12-25,2013-12-26,2013-12-27,2014-01-09,2013-12-28,2013-12-29,2013-12-30,2014-01-01,2014-01-02,2013-01-05,2014-01-03,2014-01-04,2014-01-05,2014-01-10,2014-01-08,2014-01-07,2013-12-31,2014-01-06';
$array = explode(',',$date);
sort($array);
```

Comment: в результате получается `1`, а мне нужен список дат, упорядоченный по дням (возрастанию), вот такой:

`$date2 = '2013-12-25,2013-12-26,2013-12-27,2013-12-28,2013-12-29,2013-12-30,2013-12-31,2014-01-01,2014-01-02,2014-01-03,2014-01-04,2014-01-05,2014-01-06,2014-01-07,2014-01-08,2014-01-09,2014-01-10,2014-01-11';`

Comment: видимо потому, что Вы выводите так

    echo sort($array).

а нужно так

    sort($array);
    $date2 = join(',', $array);
    echo( $date2 );